# Can't start solr on Ubuntu Server

Tags: solr, ubuntu-16.04

Recently I was trying to learn Apache Solr, but I have some problems with running it.

To install Solr I was using this guide: [Solr Install](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-solr-on-ubuntu-14-04)

After runnig `/opt/solr# java -jar start.jar` not much happens.

```
7688 [searcherExecutor-5-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore  – QuerySenderListener done.
7688 [searcherExecutor-5-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.handler.component.SpellCheckComponent  – Loading spell index for spellchecker: default
7689 [searcherExecutor-5-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.handler.component.SpellCheckComponent  – Loading spell index for spellchecker: wordbreak
7689 [searcherExecutor-5-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.handler.component.SuggestComponent  – Loading suggester index for: mySuggester
7691 [searcherExecutor-5-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.spelling.suggest.SolrSuggester  – reload()
7692 [searcherExecutor-5-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.spelling.suggest.SolrSuggester  – build()
7723 [searcherExecutor-5-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore  – [collection1] Registered new searcher Searcher@689e8096[collection1] main{StandardDirectoryReader(segments_1:1:nrt)}
```

It registered a new searcher, but http://192.168.0.109:8983/solr is not running...I get ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT Any ideas? The default welcome page of Apache works fine. I'm running it on Oracle VM VirtualBox

Now I've tried with this guide: https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_0/installing-solr.html

And here is what I did:

```
solr@hubert:~/solr/solr-7.3.0$ bin/solr start
*** [WARN] *** Your open file limit is currently 1024.
 It should be set to 65000 to avoid operational disruption.
 If you no longer wish to see this warning, set SOLR_ULIMIT_CHECKS to false in your profile or solr.in.sh
*** [WARN] ***  Your Max Processes Limit is currently 7842.
 It should be set to 65000 to avoid operational disruption.
 If you no longer wish to see this warning, set SOLR_ULIMIT_CHECKS to false in your profile or solr.in.sh
Waiting up to 180 seconds to see Solr running on port 8983 [\]
Started Solr server on port 8983 (pid=3113). Happy searching!
                                                                                                                                                               solr@hubert:~/solr/solr-7.3.0$ bin/solr status

Found 1 Solr nodes:

Solr process 3113 running on port 8983
{
  "solr_home":"/home/solr/solr/solr-7.3.0/server/solr",
  "version":"7.3.0 98a6b3d642928b1ac9076c6c5a369472581f7633 - woody - 2018-03-28 14:37:45",
  "startTime":"2018-05-12T12:36:27.502Z",
  "uptime":"0 days, 0 hours, 0 minutes, 12 seconds",
  "memory":"26.1 MB (%5.3) of 490.7 MB"}

solr@hubert:~/solr/solr-7.3.0$ ps -ef | grep solr
solr      2430     1  0 14:33 ?        00:00:00 /lib/systemd/systemd --user
solr      2432  2430  0 14:33 ?        00:00:00 (sd-pam)
solr      2439  1336  0 14:33 tty1     00:00:00 -bash
root      2902  2887  0 14:35 pts/0    00:00:00 sudo su - solr
root      2903  2902  0 14:35 pts/0    00:00:00 su - solr
solr      2904  2903  0 14:35 pts/0    00:00:00 -su
solr      3113     1 39 14:36 pts/0    00:00:06 /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java -server -Xms512m -Xmx512m -XX:NewRatio=3 -XX:SurvivorRatio=4 -XX:TargetSurvivorRatio=90 -XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=8 -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:ConcGCThreads=4 -XX:ParallelGCThreads=4 -XX:+CMSScavengeBeforeRemark -XX:PretenureSizeThreshold=64m -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=50 -XX:CMSMaxAbortablePrecleanTime=6000 -XX:+CMSParallelRemarkEnabled -XX:+ParallelRefProcEnabled -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow -verbose:gc -XX:+PrintHeapAtGC -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution -XX:+PrintGCApplicationStoppedTime -Xloggc:/home/solr/solr/solr-7.3.0/server/logs/solr_gc.log -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=9 -XX:GCLogFileSize=20M -Dsolr.log.dir=/home/solr/solr/solr-7.3.0/server/logs -Djetty.port=8983 -DSTOP.PORT=7983 -DSTOP.KEY=solrrocks -Duser.timezone=UTC -Djetty.home=/home/solr/solr/solr-7.3.0/server -Dsolr.solr.home=/home/solr/solr/solr-7.3.0/server/solr -Dsolr.data.home= -Dsolr.install.dir=/home/solr/solr/solr-7.3.0 -Dsolr.default.confdir=/home/solr/solr/solr-7.3.0/server/solr/configsets/_default/conf -Xss256k -Dsolr.jetty.https.port=8983 -Dsolr.log.muteconsole -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError=/home/solr/solr/solr-7.3.0/bin/oom_solr.sh 8983 /home/solr/solr/solr-7.3.0/server/logs -jar start.jar --module=http
solr      3260  2904  0 14:36 pts/0    00:00:00 ps -ef
solr      3261  2904  0 14:36 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto solr
```

Everything seems to be fine, but I still can't run my Solr console at http://192.168.0.109:8983/solr (as I said, default apache website works fine)

```
solr@hubert:~/solr/solr-7.3.0$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_171"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_171-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.171-b11, mixed mode)

solr@hubert:~/solr/solr-7.3.0$ cat /etc/os-release
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="16.04.4 LTS (Xenial Xerus)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS"
VERSION_ID="16.04"
```

Comment: Have you tried accessing it from within the Ubuntu VBox environment itself? If so, it should just be `http://localhost:8983/solr`. Secondly, any reason you're using an installation tutorial from *over 4 years ago* that applies to a different OS version than you're using? If you're using Solr 7 (and Ubuntu 16.04, going by your tags), Apache has documentation for setting it up. Here's the link (which contains the link for setting up Solr in production): https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_0/installing-solr.html

Comment: curl --head http://192.168.0.109:8983/solr

HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Location: http://192.168.0.109:8983/solr/
Content-Length: 0

Answer (score 0):

```
ssh hubert@hubert -L 8983:192.168.0.109:8983 -p22
```

this command and rebooting server solved my problem